# Tracking with windows services

Tags: .net, vb.net, service, windows-services, interopservices

Hi there I'm trying to track, when a specific  word files opens with windows  services with these below technique but these Methods aren't working in windows services please help me, provide me a through which I can achieve that.

```
 1. Dim wordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
          wordApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")

Exception occurred: Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)) 
--------------------------------------------------------------


 2. Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")     
        For Each a In p
            FileRecord.WriteLine("Name : {0}", a.MainWindowTitle)
            'Above Line Write empty a.MainWindowTitle
        Next
```

Comment: Can you show errors received from what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Benno Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))